# Why does one of my OFDM subcarriers have a much higher gain than the rest in GNUradio?

Tags: ofdm, gnuradio, channel

I'm using a fairly standard setup after the ofdm flowgraph examples provided by gnuradio.

When I look at the absolute value of the received complex symbols in the first sync word (and every other symbol in the header), it looks something like this: [image: absolute value of gain]

The location of this peak varies slightly, but is typically around subcarriers -3 to 3. I assumed this peak to be the DC offset of the FFT, but if it is, then my question is why it's offset by up to 3 subcarriers.

I'm transmitting and receiving using USRP 2901 radios.

This doesn't actually pose much of an issue to me. The channel is computed correctly (and is much higher than the rest) for this subcarrier, and the complex symbol in the header word at this SC is equalized correctly. I'm just wondering what could be causing a spike near the center frequency like this.

For completeness, here's the channel estimation taps:
[image]. Blue is the real part, and orange is the imaginary part.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't at DC? I'm assuming your FFT size is 64 by the appearance of the graph, and it sure looks like it's in the middle to me.

Comment: Yeah, it must be. I think I have some deeper hardware issue that's causing the offset by +- 3 subcarriers.

Comment: unlikely, your synchronisation probably just isn't done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

if this is actually a received signal from hardware, this is very very likely transmitter and/or receiver DC leakage.

The USRPs you're using are all direct conversion transceivers, i.e. that leakage is "in their nature". Since most OFDM systems are, typical system design includes simply not using the DC carriers for data nor for channel estimation.

Why does it extend for three subcarriers to each side? First of all, we don't know how wide your subcarrier is, physically, and especially since I suspect this to be a close-range experiment, any non-linearity, especially that caused by having a transmitter very close to a receiver, will be time-varyingly influence the power around DC, giving the DC leak a bandwidth.

Then, you will have to check, but typically, USRPs support tuning to nearly arbitrary frequencies, by having a part of the tuning done in the FPGA in the device. That means your LO leakage doesn't end up *exactly* at DC. If it's not *exactly* at DC, the sinc shape of subcarriers means its power falls into multiple subcarriers.

By the way, in your figures, it doesn't look like it acutely spans from -3 to +3 subcarriers, but is limited to one.

If I misunderstand and you mean "why is it 1 subcarrier at a varying position", then the answer, as hinted at in the comments under your question, is that a synchronization step misbehaves.

When debugging complex systems, don't start end-to-end. You should have first visualized the spectrum of the digital signal you're sending (to verify it's not your transmitter algorithms), then you should have looked at the spectrum of your raw reception (to make sure it's not only caused by the receiver algorithms). You could have then tuned the receiver to a different frequency and see whether the peak moves as you tune, or stays stationary – that tells you whether it's caused in your receiver and/or your transmitter. Do the same with fixed receiver, varying transmitter frequency, and you'll how much is caused where.